# SQLAlchemy: Map table to semi-configured class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a use case where I would like to be able to partially define a table using the declaritive API, and later on add some column attributes corresponding to a primary key that I auto-generate after the table class is defined.

For example, say that I have this table as a starting point:

```
Base = declarative_base(cls=DeferredReflection)

class my_table(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'my_schema'}

    @hybrid_property
    def my_attr(self):
        return func.coalesce(self.attr_1, self.attr_2, self.attr_3)
```

The table has no primary keys but it has a primary index that is effectively a primary key.  SQLAlchemy doesn't use the primary index as a primary key by default.  So what I want to do is try to build the primary key from the primary index that is already available on the table.

Here is the class I wrote to accomplish this:

```
class AddPrimaryKeys():
    '''
    This class provides a function that will automatically add primary key
    definitions using the established primary index.
    '''
    def __init__(self, inspector):
        self.inspector = inspector

    def __call__(self, table, metadata):
        pkey_cols = self.__build_pkey_from_index(table)
        return self.__add_primary_keys(table, pkey_cols, metadata)

    def __build_pkey_from_index(self, table):
        tablename = table.__tablename__
        schema = table.__table_args__['schema']
        indices = self.inspector.get_indexes(tablename, schema=schema)
        pkey_info = self.__get_column_info(tablename, schema, indices)
        pkey_cols = self.__build_columns(pkey_info, table)
        return pkey_cols

    def __get_column_info(self, tablename, schema, indices):
        columns = self.inspector.get_columns(tablename, schema=schema)
        index_names = indices[0]['column_names']
        pkey_info = []
        for c in columns:
            if c['name'] in index_names:
                pkey_info.append((c['name'], c['type']))
        return pkey_info

    def __build_columns(self, pkey_info, table):
        pkey_cols = []
        for key_name, key_type in pkey_info:
            column = Column(key_name, key_type, primary_key=True)
            pkey_cols.append(column)
        print(pkey_cols)
        return pkey_cols

    def __add_primary_keys(self, table, pkey_cols, metadata):
        tablename = table.__tablename__
        schema = table.__table_args__['schema']
        table_map = Table(name=tablename, metadata=metadata, schema=schema, *pkey_cols)
        # properties={'primary_key':pkey_cols}
        # mapper(table, table_map, properties=properties)
        mapper(table, table_map)
        return metadata
```

I call the class like so:

```
insp = inspect(td_engine)
from lib.pkey_lookup import AddPrimaryKeys
add_pkeys = AddPrimaryKeys(insp)
add_pkeys(my_table, Base.metadata)
```

Here is what a column list might look like:

```
[Column('some_attr', DECIMAL(precision=18), table=None, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('another_attr', DECIMAL(precision=18), table=None, primary_key=True, nullable=False)]
```

This throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'Column' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'tables'
```

You can also see that I toyed around with just trying to declare the primary_key columns as part of the properties dict, in which case I would discard the whole `__build_columns` method.

Does anyone have any advice on how to address the error perhaps a better way to assign the columns identified from `insp.get_indexes()` as primary keys on the table?

EDIT:  Should also add that at the end of this I would like to call `Base.prepare(engine)` to populate the rest or the table attributes from the database.

Comment: Are you using teradata? If so, see this comment in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541761/sqlalchemy-reflected-table-not-seeing-primary-key#comment90054807_51541761

Comment: Correct, I am using Teradata.  I should have added that in the problem statement.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I asked that question because initially I was confused about SQLAlchemy's primary key requirement.  Now I'm trying to write a function that will automatically assign the primary key to a SQLAlchemy table based on some list of columns names that I determine based on a primary index.

Comment: I completely missed that it was actually your question as well, apologies! Just remembered seeing something similar before.